# How to make an outer div with fixed dimensions shows a portion of its inner content without changing their positions

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div contains inner html tags. i want to view only a portion ,with certain dimensions specified in outer div style,of the inner tags without squeezing the inner content to fit the outer dimensions.i think it is clear enough

my try:
these are my inner content

```
`<div id="innerDiv1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Aqua"></div>
 <div id="innerDiv2" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Red"></div>
 <div id="innerDiv3" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Yellow;position:absolute; left:100px; top:80px"></div>
 <div id="innerDiv4" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Fuchsia; position:absolute; left:100px; top:20px"></div>
 <div id="innerDiv5" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Lime"></div>`
```

i tried to add outer div cover all of the inner and show only portion of its inner content without changing their positions and hiding any thing out of the rang of the outer div which have  dimensions of (50X50) ,but i didn't get the right result

```
   <div id="outerDiv" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Orange">
     <div id="innerDiv1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Aqua"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv2" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Red"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv3" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Yellow;position:absolute; left:100px; top:80px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv4" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Fuchsia; position:absolute; left:100px; top:20px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv5" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Lime"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

user overflow:hidden in outer box css

```
 <div id="outerDiv" style=" overflow:hidden;width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Orange">
     <div id="innerDiv1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Aqua"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv2" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Red"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv3" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Yellow;position:absolute; left:100px; top:80px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv4" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Fuchsia; position:absolute; left:100px; top:20px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv5" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Lime"></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="outerDiv" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Orange; position:absolute; overflow:hidden">
     <div id="innerDiv1" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Aqua"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv2" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Red"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv3" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Yellow;position:absolute; left:100px; top:80px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv4" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Fuchsia; position:absolute; left:100px; top:20px"></div>
     <div id="innerDiv5" style=" width:50px; height:50px; background-color:Lime"></div>
</div>
```